# How can I lock my object using C# in dll

Tags: c#, bitmap

I have an i/p camera and a function that is repeating and receiving each frame.

```
public Bitmap ProcessFrame(Bitmap frame)
{

}
```

Here is the buffering place I am buffering last 100 bitmaps:

```
lock (writer)
{
   BM[now] = new Bitmap(frame);
   now = (now == 99) ? 0 : now + 1;
}
```

When I press record to record video, I need to save every buffered bitmaps and after that I have to save incoming bitmaps that are received after pressing record. So when I press Record and using the code below to save buffered bitmaps to video file I lose some of my incoming frames. The incoming frames while processing this section, are dropped and I don't want to drop them.

```
lock (writer)
{
   for (int i = now; i < 150; i++)
   {
      if (BM[i] == null)
        break;
      writer.WriteVideoFrame(BM[i]);//adding frame to an existing open file
   }
   if (now != 0)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < now - 1; i++)
      {
         writer.WriteVideoFrame(BM[i]);//adding frame to an existing open file
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the part for incoming frames to be saved in video file

```
 lock (writer)
 {
    writer.WriteVideoFrame(frame);//adding frame to an existing open file
 }
```

I have searched and found that lock will help me. When saving buffered bitmaps lock will lock writer so another bitmap that has come will be stop at writer and wait to be unlocked, but it did not help.

What should I do? how can I make a safe thread? I am using opensource ispy and i think it will make thread for each frame and call this thread. Help me to save my incoming frame.

Comment: Instead of using multiple threads, use only 2 threads. First thread to add incoming frames to a buffer queue. Second thread to process the frames from queue one by one. The only question that remain will be that how will you access the common queue from two separate threads. I suppose you could use locks then.

Comment: i am using ispy opensource and i can add a plugin there. i think they are using thread before calling this function from this dll. every new frame will call this ProcessFrame function. @user12572

Comment: i mean an ip camera is giving us a 30 fps video and and each frame will run this plugin or dll that has this function. if one calling takes longer, other will drop their frames.

Comment: If iSpy is dropping frames that arrive while your code is processing the previous frame then you only have one course of action, make your code faster.

Comment: ispy has this code for calling my process.

` private void VideoNewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs e)
        { 
  lock (_sync)
            {  
   try
                {
     if (CW.Camobject.alerts.active && Plugin != null && Alarm!=null)
                    {
                        bmOrig = RunPlugin(bmOrig); //bmOrig is a bitmap frame that is received
                    }
     
    }
   }
  } 
`

Comment: and here is RunPlugin function:

'private Bitmap RunPlugin(Bitmap bmOrig)
        { 
  var o = _plugin.GetType();
            try
   {
    //pass and retrieve the latest bitmap from the plugin
    bmOrig = (Bitmap) o.GetMethod("ProcessFrame").Invoke(Plugin, new object[] {bmOrig});
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
    ErrorHandler?.Invoke(ex.Message);
            }       
   return bmOrig;
  }'

@LasseV.Karlsen sorry i couldn't make code to be shown like code!!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a silly fixed array type solution, why not use ConcurrentQueue? Then you won't have to deal with threading since that's a thread safe class. Have one thread pulling frames from the head of the queue and writing them and have the other thread add.

Comment: do you have a simple sample code? i have never used the thing you said. i want to store all frames and after store receiving frames. so i think time consuming will be same.is that true?

Comment: i used ConcurrentQueue but it is still dropping some frames @SledgeHammer